# How do I modify the defaul graphdb.home directory?

Tags: configuration, graphdb

I have installed GraphDB Free v9.3 in LinuxMint 19.3. 
The workbench is running fine though I haven't created any repositories yet. This is because I have noticed that although the application is installed at /opt/graphdb-free, the data, conf and log files are in a hidden folder below my home folder: /home/ianpiper/.graphdb/conf (etc).

I would prefer to store these folders on a separate volume, mounted at /mnt/bigdata. In the documentation it suggests that I can set graphdb.home using the graphdb.properties file (though I don't seem to have such a file in my installation) or in the startup script. I *think* this script might be /opt/graphdb-free/app/bin/setvars.in.sh, and that I could use this to change
-Dgraphdb.home=""
to
-Dgraphdb.home="/mnt/bigdata"

Could a knowledgeable person advise as to whether my understanding is correct, and if so what the best way is to change the location of graphdb.home?

Thanks,

Ian.

Comment: This is an update to my question. I have found that the Workbench Settings dialog allows me to set the data, conf, work and logs directories. However although I also added a setting for graphdb.home this is ignored, and the home folder is still ~/.graphdb. I can live with this but it still feels a bit odd, so I'd like to know how to get the home folder in the right place. Thanks for any help you can offer on this.